# Classpath and dependency issues while Migrating from ant to gradle

Tags: gradle, ant

### Build.xml

```
<project name="DikshaPortal" default="dist" basedir=".">
<description>Build file for Portalv2.0 project</description>
<!-- set global properties for this build -->

<property name="src" location="src" />
<property name="conf" location="src/conf" />
<property name="build" location="${BUILD_TARGET}/Portal" />
<property name="GUI" location="../GUI" />
<property name="dist" location="${BUILD_EXPORT}/Portal" />
<property name="BaseDir" location="../DikshaPortal-Release-2013-12-12" />
<property name="UIBaseDir" location="../Portalv2.0_FlexCompileFiles" />
<property name="history" location="${UIBaseDir}/history" />
<property name="META-INF" location="WebContent/META-INF" />
<property name="com" location="${UIBaseDir}/com" />
<property name="pages" location="${UIBaseDir}/pages" />
<property name="WEB-INF" location="WebContent/WEB-INF" />
<property name="data" location="WebContent/data" />
<property name="temp" location="WebContent/temp" />
<property name="policies" location="WebContent/assets/images/Policies" />
<property name="TPL" value="${LIBRARIES}/ThirdParty" />
<property name="apache" value="${TPL}/apache_libs" />

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${TPL}" includes="*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${apache}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${WEB-INF}" includes="**/*.jar" />
</path>

<target name="clean" description="Removes the temporary directories used">
    <delete dir="${GUI}" />
    <delete dir="${build}" />
</target>

<target name="init" depends="clean">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp />
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist}" />
    <mkdir dir="${GUI}" />
    <mkdir dir="${data}" />
    <mkdir dir="${temp}" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compile the source code">
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" debug="on" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" classpathref="classpath" />
</target>


<target name="dist" depends="compile" description="generate the distribution">

    <copy todir="${GUI}">
        <fileset dir="${UIBaseDir}" includes="*.js,*.html,*.swf,*.jsp,favicon.png,favicon.ico" />
    </copy>
    <mkdir dir="${GUI}/assets/images/Policies" />
    <copy todir="${GUI}/assets/images/Policies">
        <fileset dir="${policies}" includes="*.*" />
    </copy>
    <mkdir dir="${GUI}/data" />
    <copy todir="${GUI}/data">
        <fileset dir="${data}" includes="**" />
    </copy>
    <mkdir dir="${GUI}/temp" />
    <copy todir="${GUI}/temp">
        <fileset dir="${temp}" includes="*.*" />
    </copy>
    <mkdir dir="${GUI}/history" />
    <copy todir="${GUI}/history">
        <fileset dir="${history}" includes="*.*" />
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="${GUI}/com" />
    <copy todir="${GUI}/com">
        <fileset dir="${com}" includes="**" />
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="${GUI}/pages" />
    <copy todir="${GUI}/pages">
        <fileset dir="${pages}" includes="**" />
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="${GUI}/WEB-INF/flex" />
    <copy todir="${GUI}/WEB-INF/flex">
        <fileset dir="${WEB-INF}/flex" includes="*.*">
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="${GUI}/WEB-INF/pages" />
    <copy todir="${GUI}/WEB-INF/pages">
        <fileset dir="${WEB-INF}/pages" includes="*.*">
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="${dist}/conf" />
    <copy todir="${dist}/conf">
        <fileset dir="${BaseDir}/conf" includes="email.properties, Portal.properties" />
    </copy>

    <copy todir="${dist}">
        <fileset dir="${BaseDir}/conf" includes="readme.txt" />
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="${dist}/email/templates" />
    <copy todir="${dist}/email/templates">
        <fileset dir="${BaseDir}/email/templates" includes="*.*" />
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="${dist}/jasper" />
    <copy todir="${dist}/jasper">
        <fileset dir="${BaseDir}/jasper" includes="*.*" />
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="${dist}/conf" />
    <copy todir="${dist}">
        <fileset dir="${BaseDir}/db_scripts" includes="*.*" />
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="${dist}/jars" />
    <copy todir="${dist}/jars">
        <fileset dir="${TPL}" includes="*.*" />
    </copy>

    <copy todir="${build}" file="src/MessageResources.properties">
    </copy>

    <!--
        Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.war file
    -->
    <war destfile="${dist}/DikshaPortalv2.0.war" webxml="${WEB-INF}/web.xml" basedir="${GUI}">
        <classes dir="${build}" />
        <lib dir="${WEB-INF}/lib" />
        <webinf dir="${WEB-INF}" includes="*.xml" excludes="web.xml" />
        <fileset dir="${META-INF}" />
    </war>

    <copy todir="${build}">
        <fileset dir="${dist}" includes="*.war" />
    </copy>


    <delete dir="${GUI}" />
    <delete dir="${build}" />

</target>
```

### Build.gradle

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
```

### Project Structure

[image: project structure]

### Output

[image: classpath no dependencies]

### Requirements

Migration from ant to gradle, I did was import the ant's build.xml
into Gradle's build.gradle file, The build was successful when I did
try to build the project,but i get to see the below two lines in the
output.
classpath 
No dependency
please do help me out.

Comment: Your Ant script doesn't contain a target named "build". Try running one of the targets you actually have.

Comment: $ gradle dist

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'dist' not found in root project 'perdiem'. Some candidates are: 'test'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s

Comment: $gradle compile

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'compile' is ambiguous in root project 'perdiem'. Candidates are: 'compileJava', 'compileTestJava'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compile'.
> /home/nfshome/vijay.rajagopal/pristine/branches/lynx-api/perdiem/${LIBRARIES}/ThirdParty does not exist.

Comment: please do help me with the above error

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what your issue is. I just tested it on my own machine and it works fine. That said, importing a build.xml into a Gradle script is not a "migration" to Gradle. If you really want to migrate, you should rewrite the code.

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compile'.
> /home/nfshome/vijay.rajagopal/pristine/branches/lynx-api/perdiem/${LIBRARIES}/ThirdParty does not exist.

Comment: when i did try to compile, that said thirdparty does not exist

Comment: It's trying to resolve old properties provided by Eclipse or whatever IDE you used to generate that script. Seriously, you should just buckle down and write your own Gradle script. It's not that hard.